# Unknown compiler option 'outFile'

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

I was trying to compile some `TypeScript` files to single `JavaScript`.
Getting error as below

> error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'outFile'.

I compile it by command `tsc`. if I use outDir, the .ts files are compiling as expected to .js but seperately.

My tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outFile": "../../built/local/tsc.js",
    "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

TypeScript version : 2.6.2

I tried changing the module, but no positive result.
How can I overcome this?

Comment: TypeScript 5.6.0?  You sure about that?  The latest release is 2.6.

Comment: sorry guys. typo.. copied wrong thing.. updated the query

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of TypeScript installed?  You are likely (unknowingly) compiling with a 1.x compiler.  `outFile` was added in 2.0.

Comment: i have uninstalled typescript and installed it again. same dude.

Comment: @Amy : the problem is i have extension in VSCode which is of some older version. uninstalling it solves the problem. Thank you for your support anyways. If needed, you can post your comment as answer, will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have multiple versions of TypeScript installed? You are likely (unknowingly) compiling with a 1.x compiler. `outFile` was added in 2.0.